# Why image don't hide when I set INVISIBLE?

Tags: android, image, invisible, fragment-transitions

I am trying to use FragmentTransition library of **bherbst** in github:
[FragmentTransitionSample](https://github.com/bherbst/FragmentTransitionSample)

But I want image in **DetailFragment** invisible when transition end, so  I listen this event in **GridFragment** and set image invisible:

```
@Override
public void onKittenClicked(KittenViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int kittenNumber = (position % 6) + 1;

    kittenDetails = DetailsFragment.newInstance(kittenNumber);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mDetailsTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                kittenDetails.invisibleView();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello===========>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });
    }
```

In **DetailFragment**:

```
public void invisibleView() {
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

This image **only** invisible when I click on 1st grid. Any idea, please?

Comment: did you already include the HOLDER?

Comment: This is a silly mistake. Did you try debugging? If not then do it, it will be easily caught.

Comment: Yes, I was already setOnClick in adapter:
viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onKittenClicked(viewHolder, position);
            }
        });
invisibleView() call when transition end but image hide only when click 1st cell

Comment: image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

working???

Comment: @seon It also work when click first cell only

Comment: have you debugged it?? does your problem solved or not??

Comment: @seon : I had debugged;  image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); call anytime when I click but image don't invisible on screen

Comment: Go through the Alternative way.

put in the Layout ,with invisible and dont do through Progamatically
<
visibility="invisible"
>.Lets see what it does

Comment: I have do it before, it invisible normal

Comment: can you add the screenshot what you want to achieve? and what you achieved??